# pass unknown amount of objects using one parameter objective c

Tags: ios

i'm trying to create custom alertView and i'm having problems with overriding init function

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... {
    self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil];
    //custom initialisaton
    return self;
}
```

how can i use other button titles if there is more than one title?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - variadic arguments can't be passed down from a function to another.

---

There's a workaround, however: you can parse the arguments yourself, then add them one by one to the alert view:

```
self = [super initWithTitle:title
                    message:message
                   delegate:delegate
          cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
          otherButtonTitles:nil];

va_list args;
va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);

NSString *title;
for (title = otherButtonTitles; title != nil; title = va_arg(args, NSString *)) {
        [self addButtonWithTitle:title];
}

va_end(args);
```